# Angular 2 Click event with parameter and return value

Tags: javascript, angular

This hard coded call to my generic javascript function "openTab" works and the return value from openTab is false so the code will change/show tabs without submitting the form.

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="return openTab(event,'tab1');">Tab 1</button>
```

As soon as I make this dynamic I run into several errors:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of question.options">
    <button class="tablinks" (click)="return openTab(event, option.tabId);">{{ option.tabName }}
</ng-container>
```

The above code is where I am trying to get to but the parser does not like having "(click)=return" and when I remove the return I get an exception "_co.openTab" is not a function.

Here are the things I have tried:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="return openTab(event, 'tab1');">{{ option.tabName }}</button>
```

The above works but the id is hard coded, the tabName is dynamic.

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="return openTab(event, {{option.tabId}});">{{ option.tabName }}</button>
```

The code above gives the following error: Binding to event property 'onclick' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (click)=...

```
<button class="tablinks" (click)="return openTab(event, {{option.tabId}});">{{ option.tabName }}</button>
```

The code above won't parse due to the return: Parser Error: Unexpected token

```
<button class="tablinks" (click)="openTab(event, option.tabId);">{{ option.tabName }}</button>
```

The code above parses but when you click the button you get: TypeError: _co.openTab is not a function

```
<button class="tablinks" (myClick)="openTab(event, option.tabId);">{{ option.tabName }}</button>
```

The code above parses but when you click the button nothing happens, openTab is not called, no error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `$event`: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#get-user-input-from-the-event-object. The following should work:

```
<button (click)="openTab($event, option.tabId)"></button>
```

Note that the `openTab` method must be public on the component class.

Comment: The $event and explicitly making openTab public did the trick